# How to print (using NSLog) all properties of a class automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think it's very difficult to print out the value of all properties of any class in objective-c, in the case the type of the property is complex.

But if the class that contains properties with simple types (like, NSString, int, double, boolean), is there any way to NSLog automatically instead of NSLog manually the value of each property?

***Updated***:

All the solutions you gave me are still manually. Is there any way like iterate through all properties of a class, and NSLog the **variable_name** and the **variable_value**. That's what I expected.

Comment: You can overwrite `description` method of your classes.

Comment: just add a breakpoint . you can expend that object to get all properties while debugging

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan while it can be useful to find 1-2 object properties, if you need to do larger-scale reading of several objects at once (especially if nested) then drilling down into an object during runtime gets tedious, also especially if you need to make slight tweaks and run the app about 20 times, drilling down each time.

Comment: My object is NSObject

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by overriding `-(void)description` method.

Example:
Let's say we have simple `Car` class.

```
@interface Car : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic)   NSString *model;
@property (copy, nonatomic)   NSString *make;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *registrationDate;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger mileage;
@property (assign, nonatomic) double fuelConsumption;

@end

@implementation
- (NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@:%p %@>",
            [self className],
            self,
            @{ @"model"           : self.model,
               @"make"            : self.make,
               @"registrationDate": self.registrationDate,
               @"mileage"         : @(self.mileage),
               @"fuelConsumption" : @(self.fuelConsumption)
            }];
}
@end
```

Putting this in `NSDictionary` will create very nice output in console.

On the other hand, you can create category on `NSObject` class and do something like this:

```
- (NSString*)myDescriptionMethod {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    unsigned int count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const char *property = property_getName(properties[i]);
        NSString *propertyString = [NSString stringWithCString:property encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
        id obj = [self valueForKey:propertyString];
        [dict setValue:obj forKey:propertyString];
    }

    free(properties);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ %p %@>",
            [self class],
            self,
            dict];
}
```

Then you will avoid overriding `-(void)description` method in your classes.

Get it from [here](https://github.com/tailec/NSObject-Description-category)

Comment: I got an error: "Declaration of 'objc_property_t' must be imported from module 'ObjectiveC.runtime' before it is required"

Comment: @chipbk10 use `#import "objc/runtime.h"`

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way to achieve what you're looking for in **Objective-C** with **`NSObject`** subclasses, it to override the **`NSObject`** method `description`.

**For example (assuming your Class has a property called propertyX):**

```
-(NSString *)description
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<myCustomObject: %@, propertyX: %f, %f>",
                 [self objectID], [self propertyX].x, [self propertyX].y];
}
```

The default `description` implementation of **`NSObject`** will simply return the memory address pointed to for the object, like so:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self);
```

> 2015-06-15 14:20:30.123 AppName[...] myCustomObject: 0x000000>

However, by overriding this base Class method as shown above, you will be able to customise this behavior, and the log will look like this:

> 2015-06-15 14:20:30.123 AppName[...] myCustomObject: 0x000000 someProperty, Property: blah, blah>

There is a nice tutorial, which discusses this further [here](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/01/overriding-nsobjects-description/).

Answer (score -5):

Example :-

```
 + (NSString *)description;
    [NSString description];
```

Gives you information about the class NSString.